# How to use reflection with Mockito mock objects

Tags: java, mockito

I'm trying to test some Java code that uses reflection, and as part of the test I need to create an object that is a different type to the object under test but that shares the same (abstract) parent (actually, an `Optional` wrapping the object). I am testing a predicate of the form:

```
abstractForm.isPresent() && (abstractForm.get().getClass() != this.getClass())
```

(not my design - don't blame me!) and need to create a mock object for `abstractForm`. If I create it with Mockito, simply using `SacmElement citedElement = mock(SacmElement.class)` it actually all works just fine *except* I get a warning:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$2 (file:/C:/Users/owner/.m2/repository/org/mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/mockito-core-1.10.19.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$2
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

So it works *for now*, but it isn't likely to keep working. Is this going beyond what Mockito can do, or is there a non-deprecated way of getting at the class of a Mockito mocked object?

Comment: are you able to modify that code that's doing the class comparison? Ideally you'd switch it to an instanceof comparison...

Comment: It has to be exactly the same class, not a subclass, unfortunately. Although I suppose `(a instanceof b) && (b instanceof a)` would do that... (There are just a couple of cases in the inheritance hierarchy imposed on me where a non-abstract class is inherited - just enough to be a nuisance.)

Comment: Doesn’t mockito actually create a subclass of the class being mocked? (Which would be why it can’t mock final classes)? Maybe it’s fancier than that, but it seems it would be the simplest implementation (I’ve never actually dove that far into the impl so I may be wrong)

Comment: you can temporary use the JPMS flag --add-opens to allow reflective access to your modules of choice, or, if those are un-named modules: --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED. This can be used inside the run configurations of your application in your IDE as JVM flag, or as an <argLine> inside the <configuration> element of maven-surefire-plugin (if used)

Answer (score 13):

Just stumbled into this question while I was searching for its answer. I realized from [this github issue](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-cglib/issues/1) that I was using an old version of mockito.

I simply updated from this version

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

to this version

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

The trick was that the `artifactId` has changed and that Google sends you the link to the older `artifactId` on lookup for "mockito maven".